# Changing document.write into the appropriate element.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

So, I'm new to learning js. And I know that document.write is outdated and the new solution is element.innerHTML. I'm working through some tutorial, but in testing my code it's breaking. What would be the appropriate means of going about inserting element.innerHTML and it's accompanying code, to get this to work?

Below is my snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>8. Javascript Arrays</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>8. Javascript Arrays</h1>
    <script>
<div id="flightDate"></div>
<div id="myValues"></div>

var flightDate = new Date("September 22, 2004");
var myValues = ["Oceanic", 815, flightDate];

for (i in myValues)
{
    document.write("<br />" + myValues[i]);
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display the output in the DIVs that you created.

```
document.getElementById('flightDate').innerHTML = flightDate;
for (i = 0; i < myValues.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('myValues').innerHTML += myValues[i] + '<br/>';
}
```

`+=` concatenates the value with the content that's already there.